# Cannot connect to database using static IP address + port in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin, port

I have an existing application that connects to the MySQL database (using WampServer). I can use `localhost` as the name of my server.

I tried using the static IP address instead of `localhost`. The database can be accessed from `http://192.168.1.1:1234/phpmyadmin`.

I already set up my app.config this way:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MyConnection" value="Data Source=192.168.1.1;Port=1234;Database=mydb;UID=root;" />
  </appSettings>
```

but receiving an error when I tried to run the application:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond.

Any suggestions what to do?

Comment: To be clear -- you *could* use "localhost" instead of "192.168.1.1" and it works?

Comment: Yes. It is working for 'localhost'

Comment: Seems pretty low-level; you're sure `telnet 192.168.1.1 1234` succeeds in a command prompt?

Comment: `localhost`, yes. But what port?

Comment: It works without any port number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The database can be accessed from `http://192.168.1.1:1234/phpmyadmin`

This just means that your *webserver* and *PHP* is running at  `192.168.1.1` on port `1234`. This doesn't tell us anything about where *MySQL* is running.

If PHPMyAdmin is working correctly, and you can see your databases, then you could look in the PHPMyAdmin config file for the MySQL connection info.

Typically, if configured for TCP, MySQL listens on port 3306.  I would try changing your connection string to

```
Data Source=192.168.1.1;Port=3306;...
```

If that doesn't work, it's probably as [user2196728 said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20341933/119527), that MySQL is only listening on the local loopback adapter (127.0.0.1), which is more secure. In that case, you should use `localhost` in your connection string, or change the config file to listen on 0.0.0.0, which means all adapters with an IP address.

Comment: Just trying to explain things in a few more words. Either way, his port number is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

By default, phpmyadmin listen on localhost (127.0.0.1). You have to modify the config file to listen on 0.0.0.0

Or just comment this line in your /etc/my.cnf :

```
#bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

And restart your mysql server